# Why does Google Analytics report a spammer as the "GuzzleHTTP" user agent?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

I got my GA account spammed, somehow google recognizes it as Guzzle client. However I tried to search through my access logs, for something resembling it, but did not find anything at all even containing word 'guzzle', but google somehow recognizes it, you can see it here:

[image: GA]

Any ideas what this could be? And how I could recognize it? 
By the way, I am almost sure that it is indeed someone crawling the actual pages, as opposed to someone just sending hits directly to GA.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that Google recognises the default Guzzle user-agent from the request headers it sends out.

[See the Guzzle documentation here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=user-agent)

The raw user-agent isn't visible in GA, so that'd explain why you can't find it anywhere in your reports.